# Creating dict groupby from two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, tree, pivot-table

I want to achieve the following when Back is equal to 1.

Logic is the following:
8582 is the main node level is 1 and has 4 sub node (8584,8593,8585,8586) and each of those sub nodes have sub nodes
Idea is to groupby in json structure or tree to be able to visualize the structure and sum of amounts i've the following code but it's not exactly what i want to get:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict
import json

data = {
    'Nod': [8582, 8586, 8585, 8593, 8584, 8590, 8583, 8597, 8587, 8674, 8589, 8588],
    'Levels': [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
    'Parents': [None, 8582, 8582, 8582, 8582, 8586, 8593, 8584, 8585, 8586, 8586, 8585],
    'Names': ['Xhelp', 'Hd', 'Ejjd', 'Mmmm', 'Awe', 'Urj', 'Bdh', 'Ddj', 'Lsk', 'Bws', 'Jsk', 'Pqq'],
    'ID': [90, 89, 92, 85, 37, 28, 19, 34, 11, 83, 433, 37]
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

data2 = {
    'ID': [10, 90, 89, 92, 85, 37, 28, 19, 34, 11, 83, 433, 433, 19],
    'Amounts': [1288, 998, 7338, 9337, 784, 3884, 399, 8559, 5146, 9348, 111, 8445, 40, 90],
    'Back': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)


def nested_dict():
    return defaultdict(nested_dict)


tree = nested_dict()

for _, row in df1.iterrows():
    node = {
        "Levels": row["Levels"],
        "Names": row["Names"],
        "ID": row["ID"],
        "Amounts": 0,
    }

    parent_id = row["Parents"]
    if parent_id is None:
        tree[row["Nod"]] = node
    else:
        parent_node = tree[parent_id]
        parent_node["children"][row["Nod"]] = node

for _, row in df2.iterrows():
    node_id = row["ID"]
    amount = row["Amounts"]
    if node_id in tree:
        tree[node_id]["Amounts"] += amount

json_tree = json.dumps(tree, indent = 2)

print(json_tree)
```

New data :

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = """Nod Levels Parents Amounts
8616 1 NaN 0
8636 5 8648 0
8637 5 8635 0
8631 4 8630 0
8605 5 8609 8888882
8606 5 8609 339494
8609 4 8615 0
8613 6 8620 0
8614 6 8636 0
8615 3 8642 0
8618 6 8620 49832
8619 6 8636 11122
8620 5 8648 0
8621 4 8615 0
8622 5 8621 237837
8623 5 8621 0
8624 4 8615 0
8625 5 8624 87328732
8634 4 8627 0
8639 5 8634 0
8648 4 8627 0
8630 3 8642 0
8632 4 8615 0
8627 3 8642 0
8629 5 8609 -8378383
8633 5 8632 0
8635 4 8627 0
8638 5 8634 -93198318
8638 5 8634 32323
8642 2 8616 0"""

# Create a DataFrame from the provided data
df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep=' ')
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you add expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```py
df1 = df1.merge(df2[df2.Back == 1], on="ID")

dct, index = {}, {}
for _, row in df1.iterrows():
    a = row["Amounts"]
    if pd.isna(row["Parents"]):
        dct[row["Nod"]] = index[row["Nod"]] = {"Amounts": a}
    else:
        if row["Parents"] not in index:
            index[row["Parents"]] = {}
        index[row["Parents"]][row["Nod"]] = index[row["Nod"]] = {"Amounts": a}


def sum_dct(dct):
    a = 0
    for k, v in dct.items():
        if k != "Amounts":
            a += sum_dct(v)

    if len(dct) > 1:
        dct["Amounts"] = a

    return dct["Amounts"]


for v in dct.values():
    sum_dct(v)

print(dct)
```

Prints:

```py
{
    8582: {
        "Amounts": 35892,
        8586: {
            "Amounts": 8955,
            8590: {"Amounts": 399},
            8674: {"Amounts": 111},
            8589: {"Amounts": 8445},
        },
        8585: {"Amounts": 13232, 8588: {"Amounts": 3884}, 8587: {"Amounts": 9348}},
        8593: {"Amounts": 8559, 8583: {"Amounts": 8559}},
        8584: {"Amounts": 5146, 8597: {"Amounts": 5146}},
    }
}
```

---

The merged dataframe looks like:

```
     Nod  Levels  Parents  Names   ID  Amounts  Back
0   8582       1      NaN  Xhelp   90      998     1
1   8586       2   8582.0     Hd   89     7338     1
2   8585       2   8582.0   Ejjd   92     9337     1
3   8593       2   8582.0   Mmmm   85      784     1
4   8584       2   8582.0    Awe   37     3884     1
5   8588       3   8585.0    Pqq   37     3884     1
6   8590       3   8586.0    Urj   28      399     1
7   8583       3   8593.0    Bdh   19     8559     1
8   8597       3   8584.0    Ddj   34     5146     1
9   8587       3   8585.0    Lsk   11     9348     1
10  8674       3   8586.0    Bws   83      111     1
11  8589       3   8586.0    Jsk  433     8445     1
```

Comment: This is exactly what i want as structure but amounts are off ... for example 8586 :  Amount should be 399+ 111+ 8445=8955

Comment: @Gogo78 But the amount for 8586 itself is 7338 and then 399 + 111 + 8445 is so the sum is 16293

Comment: Ah I mean, it's for reference the amount we have for 8586, the true value will be the same of sub nodes sorry for missleading

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to visualise this dict in nice way to show the amounts in front of each node  ?

Comment: @Gogo78 That I left as an exercise to the reader ;) Hint: traverse the `dct` recursively, check if the dict has only one key (`Amount`), if yes, change the dict to the value of the `Amount`

Comment: I’ve managed to create a nice tree now i found a bug in the code what if parents doesn’t start with Nan we get wrong results I don’t understand why  and also changing data structure with more nodes it doesn't work

Comment: @Gogo78 If there are for example, cycles then the code needs to be changed.  The post from @Quang Hoang mentions `networkx`, which is good module for working with graphs, worth looking at.

Comment: I've added new data structure in post

Comment: @Gogo78 I'd suggest to open a new question here on StackOverflow - where you put the new data, the code what have you tried so far and expected result.

Comment: I tried everything I could but didn't manage to find a solution; your code also doesn't work with my data structure .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76963698/creating-dict-groupby-from-dataframe-with-node-structure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255021/discussion-between-gogo78-and-andrej-kesely).

Comment: if you have time please have a look ... i am very stuck ...

Answer (score 0):

This is a network/graph problem and can be treated as such with [`networkx`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/index.html):

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df2.query('Back==1').merge(df1, on='ID'),
                        source='Parents',
                        target='Nod',
                        edge_attr=['Amounts'],
                           create_using=nx.DiGraph)

nx.to_dict_of_dicts(G,)
```

Output:

```
{nan: {8582: {'Amounts': 998}},
 8582: {8586: {'Amounts': 7338},
  8585: {'Amounts': 9337},
  8593: {'Amounts': 784},
  8584: {'Amounts': 3884}},
 8586: {8590: {'Amounts': 399},
  8674: {'Amounts': 111},
  8589: {'Amounts': 8445}},
 8585: {8588: {'Amounts': 3884}, 8587: {'Amounts': 9348}},
 8593: {8583: {'Amounts': 8559}},
 8584: {8597: {'Amounts': 5146}},
 8588: {},
 8590: {},
 8583: {},
 8597: {},
 8587: {},
 8674: {},
 8589: {}
}
```

You can use networkx visualization function to visualize the graph.