# Creating dict groupby from Dataframe with node structure

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've the following code :

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = """Nod Levels Parents Amounts
8616 1 NaN 0
8636 5 8648 0
8637 5 8635 0
8631 4 8630 0
8605 5 8609 8888882
8606 5 8609 339494
8609 4 8615 0
8613 6 8620 0
8614 6 8636 0
8615 3 8642 0
8618 6 8620 49832
8619 6 8636 11122
8620 5 8648 0
8621 4 8615 0
8622 5 8621 237837
8623 5 8621 0
8624 4 8615 0
8625 5 8624 87328732
8634 4 8627 0
8639 5 8634 0
8648 4 8627 0
8630 3 8642 0
8632 4 8615 0
8627 3 8642 0
8629 5 8609 -8378383
8633 5 8632 0
8635 4 8627 0
8638 5 8634 -93198318
8638 5 8634 32323
8642 2 8616 0"""

df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep=' ')

dct, index = {}, {}
for _, row in df1.iterrows():
    a = row["Amounts"]
    if pd.isna(row["Parents"]):
        dct[row["Nod"]] = index[row["Nod"]] = {"Amounts": a}
    else:
        if row["Parents"] not in index:
            index[row["Parents"]] = {}
        index[row["Parents"]][row["Nod"]] = index[row["Nod"]] = {"Amounts": a}


def sum_dct(dct):
    a = 0
    for k, v in dct.items():
        if k != "Amounts":
            a += sum_dct(v)

    if len(dct) > 1:
        dct["Amounts"] = a

    return dct["Amounts"]


for v in dct.values():
    sum_dct(v)

print(dct)
```

The idea is to groupby Nod level 1 will contain Nod level 2 and level 2 contain level 3 ...  with results will look like this
(Here it's only for 3 levels but my data in df1 is more complex) and Amounts of each Node level will be calculated as sum function of sub node

In Pivot table is easier to see the structure of this dataset it’s very complex to make a dict or Jason file of it ..

Level 8616 has sublevel 8642 which has 2 sublevels  8615 and 8627 …...

{
8616: {
"Amounts": 3882737,
8642: {
"Amounts": 7388955,
8630: {"Amounts": 399},
8615: {"Amounts": 111},
……
}

Comment: 8582 appears in your output but not your input. Can you provide a more realistic reference output?

Comment: I’ve corrected my example @Reinderien

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're computing the `Amounts` values in your example. Therefore I don't know how to deal with `Nod` duplicates (8638 in your case). But here is a recursive function that will build the desired structure from your df:

```py
from pprint import pprint

df1['Parents'] = df1['Parents'].astype('Int64').fillna(0) # parent 0 is for root element(s)

# Summing amounts of children for all levels
for lvl in sorted(df1['Levels'].unique(), reverse=True)[1:]:
    df1.loc[df1['Levels']==lvl, 'Amounts'] = df1.apply(
        lambda x: x['Amounts'] + df1.loc[df1['Parents']==x['Nod'], 'Amounts'].sum(),
        axis=1)

def build_dict(parent=0, d={}):
    d.update({r['Nod']: build_dict(r['Nod'], {'Amounts': r['Amounts']})
            for _, r in df1[df1['Parents']==parent].iterrows()})
    return d

pprint(build_dict())
```

Output:

```
{8616: {8642: {8615: {8609: {8605: {'Amounts': 8888882},
                             8606: {'Amounts': 339494},
                             8629: {'Amounts': -8378383},
                             'Amounts': 849993},
                      8621: {8622: {'Amounts': 237837},
                             8623: {'Amounts': 0},
                             'Amounts': 237837},
                      8624: {8625: {'Amounts': 87328732}, 'Amounts': 87328732},
                      8632: {8633: {'Amounts': 0}, 'Amounts': 0},
                      'Amounts': 88416562},
               8627: {8634: {8638: {'Amounts': 32323},
                             8639: {'Amounts': 0},
                             'Amounts': -93165995},
                      8635: {8637: {'Amounts': 0}, 'Amounts': 0},
                      8648: {8620: {8613: {'Amounts': 0},
                                    8618: {'Amounts': 49832},
                                    'Amounts': 49832},
                             8636: {8614: {'Amounts': 0},
                                    8619: {'Amounts': 11122},
                                    'Amounts': 11122},
                             'Amounts': 60954},
                      'Amounts': -93105041},
               8630: {8631: {'Amounts': 0}, 'Amounts': 0},
               'Amounts': -4688479},
        'Amounts': -4688479}}
```

Comment: it’s close but missing the amounts values for example 8609 nod will be the sum of 8605: {'Amounts': 8888882},
       8606: {'Amounts': 339494},
                    8629: {'Amounts': -8378383}, and etc … it’s groupby by levels where node 1 will have value of sum of node 2

Comment: This is something you can (and should!) do direct in pandas. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Note: You still haven't explained how to deal with duplicated nod values (amount for 8638).